# How do I refactor a conditional statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm on Rails 4 and Im using devise for user management. I have a simple conditional statement in a show view like this

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
    <%= link_to "Checkout", user_cart_path(current_user,@cart), method: :patch %>
<% else %>
    <%= link_to "Checkout", signin_path %>
<% end %>
```

I want to clean up my view and add make the conditional a method.

I have tried adding the method

```
def checkout_link(current_user)
    if user_signed_in?
        link_to "Checkout", user_cart_path(current_user, self), method: :patch
    else 
        link_to "Checkout", signin_path
    end
end
```

to my cart model, and replaced the conditional in my show cart view to

```
<%= @cart.checkout_link(current_user) %>
```

When I load the cart show page, I get an error

```
undefined method `user_signed_in?' for #<Cart:0x007fd015525228>
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: I'm going to ask you to apply a soft rule - "view things belong in the view". That's just a _soft_ rule; viewey things, like HTML snips, appear in the model all the time. But put the `link_to` in the view and leave the logic for what it links to in the model. That would also be more DRY.

Comment: model isnt aware of your view context, use decorators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing you are doing wrong is concerning your model with the view. This should not be done.

You should place the `checkout_link` in a view helper method. This will clean up your view, and keep the model only concerned about the data it contains.

Though, in this case, I would just have a single link that leads to the checkout, and if the user is not signed in, have a `before_filter` redirect them to sign in.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, you can either add to the view helper or use a decorator.

1. If you add the method to the view, it would look something like this:

   ```
    def checkout_link(cart)
       if user_signed_in?
           link_to "Checkout", user_cart_path(current_user,cart), method: :patch
       else 
           link_to "Checkout", signin_path
       end
    end
   ```
2. "The decorator wraps the model, and deals only with presentational concerns. In the controller, you decorate the article before handing it off to the view."<sup>1</sup> If you would like to use a decorator, check out Ryan Bates' Railscast on them: [using an existing gem](http://railscasts.com/episodes/286-draper) or [creating a decorator from scratch](http://railscasts.com/episodes/287-presenters-from-scratch).

<sup>1</sup>   Quoted from the Draper gem's README. https://github.com/drapergem/draper

Answer (score 1):

You're *almost* there.  You want your `checkout_link` method to be a "helper method" in a helper file, not in your model file.  So, create a file named `app/helpers/carts_helper.rb` and move your `checkout_link` method there.  Methods in helper files are available to views and controllers.

When I was just learning my way around Rails, I would do:

```
rails generate scaffold Dummy
```

specifically to see what files it generated, including helper files.  This might be a good place to start.